# Use set or just create keys in redis to check existence?

Tags: redis

I can think of two ways of checking existence using redis:

1. Use the whole database as a 'set', and just `SET` a key and checking existence by `GET`ing it (or using `EXISTS` as mentioned in the comment by @Sergio Tulentsev)
2. Use `SADD` to add all members to a key and check existence by `SISMEMBER`

Which one is better? Will it be a problem, compared to the same amount of keys in a single set, if I choose the first method and the number of keys in a database gets larger?

Comment: JFYI: https://redis.io/commands/exists

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev, good catch, this command can be considered the first choice, I've edited my question.

Comment: Is there a specific application that you're envisioning? I can think of advantages and disadvantages to both methods, and the "right" answer is really context-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, besides these two methods, you can also use the `HASH` data structure with `HEXISTS` command (I'll call this method as the third solution).

All these solutions are fast enough, and it's NOT a problem if you have a large `SET`, `HASH`, or keyspace.

So, which one should we use? **It depends on lots of things...**

> Does the key has value?

Keys of both the first and the third solution can have value, while the second solution CANNOT.

So if there's no value for each key, I'd prefer the second solution, i.e. `SET` solution. Otherwise, you have to use the first or third solution.

> Does the value has structure?

If the value is NOT raw string, but a data structure, e.g. `LIST`, `SET`. You have to use the first solution, since `HASH`'s value CAN only be raw string.

> Do you need to do set operations?

If you need to do intersection, union or diff operations on multiple data sets, you should use the second solution. Redis has built-in commands for these operations, although they might be slow commands.

> Memory efficiency consideration

Redis takes more memory-efficient encoding for small `SET` and `HASH`. So when you have lots of small data sets, take the second and the third solution can save lots of memory. See [this](https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization) for details.

**UPDATE**

> Do you need to set TTL for these keys?

As @dizzyf points out in the comment, if you need to set `TTL` for these keys, you have to use the first solution. Because items of `HASH` and `SET` DO NOT have expiration property. You can only set `TTL` for the entire `HASH` or `SET`, NOT their elements.

Comment: I would also like to point out that you cannot set EXPIRE TTLs for items inside of a hash or set. If you needed custom expire logic for these individual existence checks then solution 1 is likely your best option.

Comment: @dizzyf Good point! I missed that, and I'll update the answer. Thanks!

Comment: You can use [zremrangebyscore](https://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyscore) to expire items in a set. Each item in the set should have a score. This could be the timestamp of its expiration time. Then, you can set a script that expires items based on their score (timestamp). E.g. expire all items where score (timestamp) is less than the current time.